# Defining a custom card component with inner content

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I'm defining a custom `card` component with `Angular 6`.

I have the following files:

**card.component.html**

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

**card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'card.component.css' ],
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

    private content: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        // I need to replace each 'a' by an 'e' to the innerHtml
        this.content = ??? what to put here ???;
    }
}
```

I want to use my custom `card` component in the following way:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-card>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</app-card>
```

My problem is that I don't know what to put on the file: `card.component.ts` to read the inner content of my custom component on: `app.component.html`.

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: See this:https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

Comment: Use the `ng-content` tag, like in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggjden?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Best practise is passing it with @Input()   https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: what I need to do is do an small transformation on the `innerHtml`, for example, read the `<ng-content></ng-content>` and apply a transformation, for example, replace each `a` by an `e`.

Comment: Could you please, check line: 14 of this file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmdpgh?file=src/app/components/card/card.component.ts, and create a working solution by forking that project on StackBlitz.com?

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar case for modal,

For example 
childComponenet.html

```
<div> 
 <span>
     <ng-content></ng-content> -- your html will replace here
 </span>
</div>
```

ParentComponent.html

```
    <abc>
       <new html here>
    </abc>
```

For more details, you can follow the guide 
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: following your example, inside the 'abc' tag I will have plain text, where I want to replace all the 'a' instances by 'e'. how do you achieve that?, thanks!

Comment: did u mean you want to replace  a from e in a string ? is it ?
for this you can pass 
<abc> {{"abcde".replace('a','e')}} </abc>

Comment: the transformation is more complex than that and I need to do it from the component class. that was just an example.

Comment: Could you please, check line: 14 of this file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmdpgh?file=src/app/components/card/card.component.ts, and create a working solution by forking that project on StackBlitz.com?